# Ajax is not passing variable to another page?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, ajax

I want to save user `email` to database when he clicks the subscribe button. But when I enter email and click the subscribe button it passes an empty array!

**Subscribe form code:**

```
<form id="cx-subscribe-user">
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter Your Email" />
    <button type="submit" id="subscribe-button">Subscribe</button>
</form>
```

**Js code:**

```
$('#cx-subscribe-user').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var email = $('#email').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "subscribe-the-user.php",
        processData: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {email: email},
        success: function(data) {
            console.log('saved scucess');
        }
    });
});
```

In `subscribe-the-user.php` file I'm trying to var_dump the request but it's printing empty array:

```
var_dump($_GET);exit;
```

In **var_dump** I receive this empty array
`array(0) {}`

Comment: `GET`, should you not be using `POST`

Comment: `url: "subscribe-the-user.php",` needs to be `url: "subscribe-the-user.php"+email,` and remove `data: {email: email},`

Comment: The data won't be saved when you later access the page. That's not how this works.

Comment: you have onclick for the form, not the submit button. either it should be on submit or onclick for the button

Comment: Try `.on('submit'` instead. With a `onclick` every click on the form, like selecting a field with a mouse pointer will cause a click. And of course there will be no data in the field at that point

Answer (score 5, accepted):

remove the `processData`, as documentation states, it will mess up your request

> **processData (default: true)**
>
> Type: Boolean
>
> By default, data passed in
>   to the data option as an object (technically, anything other than a
>   string) will be processed and transformed into a query string, fitting
>   to the default content-type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". If
>   you want to send a DOMDocument, or other non-processed data, set this
>   option to false.
>   https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you are using an `onclick()` event on the `<form>` object, so as soon as you click in email input field to add some data, form `onclick()` event is fired and the ajax request will happen without any data in the `email` field hens submitting an empty `email` parameter to the PHP.

Change form `onclick()` to button `click()` or form `submit()`

```
$('#subscribe-button').on('click', function (e) {
```

***Also*** remove  `processData: false,` [based on documentation:- [jQuery ajax documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)]

> processData (default: true) Type: Boolean By default, data passed in
>   to the data option as an object (technically, anything other than a
>   string) will be processed and transformed into a query string, fitting
>   to the default content-type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". ***If
>   you want to send a DOMDocument, or other non-processed data, set this
>   option to false.***

Comment: Yes the issue was due to `processData: false` once I removed that it started working! Thanks a ton mate.

Comment: @Iftikharuddin  you need to change form onclick to button onclick for better experience.

Comment: I have changed it to `onSubmit` on form! So is it still better to change it to button on click?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using `POST` method

```
$('#cx-subscribe-user').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var email = $('#email').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        processData: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {email: email},
        url: "subscribe-the-user.php",
        success: function(data) {
            console.log('saved success');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Emails need some encoding before send your request

```
$.ajax({
    url: "ajax.php",
    type:'get',
    data: { email: encodeURIComponent(email)},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response) {
      //Do Something
    },
    error: function(xhr) {
    //Do Something to handle error
    }
});
```

Comment: Except using `onClick` there is a very high possibility the click will be selecting the field with the mouse in an empty state. OnSubmit would be a better choise

Comment: Yes probably I was thinking to this case too and sure onSubmit is the right choice here for multiples reasons (Validation,State ..)